# JQuery hide part of element outside viewport

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element which on click should move out of the view and only be shown about 10 percent or so. Like this screenshot:

[image]

My problem is that whenever it "hides" outside the viewport the view "extends" and becomes scrollable.

[image]

I've tried to use `overflow: hidden;` although i don't get that to work at all, also i need this to work on iOS.

Is there any way i can like cut the element with JQuery? or is there any other fixes around?

Comment: Can you show your code? Normally this would just work with `overflow:hidden`. So you must have done something wrong.

Comment: @putvande check prv.sampettersson.com, i really don't know what's going on but overflow: hidden haven't worked for me in ages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your `body`:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Your `overflow:hidden` doesn't work because your elements don't have a `width` set.

Comment: Ohh, Great didn't think of that at all. I'll remember that from now.